# What is the correct argument for d3.brushSelection()?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to get the selection values for a 1-dimensional brush, but I'm having trouble understanding what the argument for d3.brushSelection() should be. I see that the documentation says that the argument should be a node, but I don't know exactly what it means. Is it supposed to be the specific HTML element on which the brush is called on, or the svg element that holds the brush? I have tried both and both return null.

```
var xBrush = d3.brushX()
  .extent([[0,0], [xWidth,xHeight]])
  .on("brush", brushed);

xChart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "brush")
  .call(xBrush);
```

If this is how I create my brush, how could I get the value of the selection? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The node desired in the argument for `d3.brushSelection` is the `g` element corresponding to your brush.

So you could access the selection either via

`d3.brushSelection(d3.select(".brush").node())`

or, with a slight change to your code,

```
var xBrush = d3.brushX()
  .extent([[0,0], [xWidth,xHeight]])
  .on("brush", brushed);

var theBrush = xChart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "brush")
  .call(xBrush);

d3.brushSelection(theBrush.node());
```

Note that if your brush's selection is empty, the function returns `null`.

Comment: `selection.node()` returns the first (non-null) element in this selection. If the selection is empty, returns null. [official document](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection)